# Как расставить знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Снова из текста по соционике: "Творческая волевая сенсорика Драйзера особенно ярко проявляется в экстремальной ситуации — при защите его интересов и главное при защите интересов его взаимоотношений".
Нужно ли как-то выделять "главное" и вообще, правильно ли расставлены тут знаки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Слово *главное* нужно выделить, это вводное слово, оно грамматически никак не связано с другими словами. Вместо тире по строгим правилам надо ставить двоеточие, так как вторая часть поясняет первую (в какой именно ситуации), но на практике часто двоеточие заменяется автором на тире.